# Error: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I've added a frame with youtube video in WebView. It works fine.

```
webView.loadHTMLString("<html><head><title>.</title><style>body,html,iframe{margin:0;padding:0;}</style></head><body><iframe width=\"" + String(describing: w) + "\" height=\"" + String(describing: h) + "\" src=\"" + livestream.Url + "?&playinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

Then I did the same for livestream.com video.
I got these errors:

- CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
- SURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
  (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
- Received memory warning.

I also added data in Info.plist file:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>          
        <key>livestream.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```